# Adding two edge labels in graph

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, label, edges

I've the following graph,

```
s = [1 1 1 2 2];
t = [2 3 4 2 5];
G = graph(s,t);
h = plot(G);
weights = [5 10 15 10 10];
% I could add one edge label using labeledge command
labeledge(h,1:numedges(G),weights);

% label2
% labeledge(h,1:numedges(G),['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5']); % I want to add this
```

I'd like to add a second edge label, the first label above the edge and the other label below the edge.

Answer (score 1):

I was used this in one of my work, I hope it's work for you too.

```
 edgelabelstr = string(g.Edges.precipitation) + " | " + string(g.Edges.runoff); 
%I showed precipitation and runoff label together
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I'd like to know if there is a way to position one label above the edge and the other label below the edge